# Show / hide menu according to user privilege

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, privileges

I have a **Ionic app** which have tabs + menu, this problem is specific to menu.

I define my side-menu in **index.html** like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
  <div>

<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" data-componentid="side-menu21">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"> </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-notifications" menu-toggle="right" ></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left" id="side-menu21">

        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <div class="title">Menu</div>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">

            <ion-list id="menu-list2" class=" " data-componentid="list2">

                <ion-item id="menu-list-item1" ui-sref="myProfile"> 
                  <i class="icon ion-person" ></i> My Profile </ion-item>

                <ion-item id="menu-list-item15" ui-sref="broadcast "> 
                  <i class="icon ion-contrast" ></i> Broadcast </ion-item>

            </ion-list>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a service which fires at **login** which bring me my authorities

```
{ "authorities": 
       [
         "myProfile","broadcast"
       ]
}
```

that I later store in **localstorage** like this

```
window.localStorage.setItem("authority", data.authorities);
```

What I wish to do is, **show or hide menu dynamically according to authorities I got from login?**

for example in authorities if instead of `"myProfile","broadcast"` there is only `"myProfile"` then broadcast should not be shown in side-menu.

Comment: What you like hide and what you like show in the side menu

Comment: check the index.html page. I wish to hide/show menus which are not in the authorities json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-hide` or `ng-if` directives.

```
<ion-item ng-if="hasAuthority('broadcast')" id="menu-list-item15" ui-sref="broadcast "> 
                  <i class="icon ion-contrast" ></i> Broadcast
</ion-item>
```

And then in controller have a function

```
$scope.hasAuthority = function(auth){
    //code to check if localstorage has needed permission
    //return true or false
}
```